# Float data type will not work with bankers rounding -- SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, bankers-rounding

To provide some background, I am currently working on a project of transitioning an Access database and its code to SQL.

In the process I changed Access data types of `Double` to `Float` in SQL Server; I did this because these data types are closely related and because my database performs a lot of division and multiplication (something I heard floats were best for).

Another issue of converting the database arose in the fact that Access uses bankers rounding whereas SQL does not; I went out and found two UD bankers rounding functions, both are not yielding consistent bankers rounding results as they should.

Is this inconsistency something I should expect when trying to run these bankers rounding functions (which include subtraction and addition) on float numbers?

The following are the two functions...

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[RB](@Val FLOAT, @Digits INT)
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
RETURN CASE WHEN ABS(@Val - ROUND(@Val, @Digits, 1)) * POWER(10, @Digits+1) = 5
           THEN ROUND(@Val, @Digits, CASE WHEN CONVERT(INT, ROUND(ABS(@Val) * 
                         POWER(10,@Digits), 0, 1)) % 2 = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
           ELSE ROUND(@Val, @Digits)
       END
END


FUNCTION [dbo].[RoundBanker]
( @Amt   NUMERIC(38,16)
, @RoundToDecimal TINYINT
) 
RETURNS NUMERIC(38,16)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @RoundedAmt NUMERIC(38,16)
,   @WholeAmt       INT
,   @Decimal        TINYINT
,   @Ten            NUMERIC(38,16)
SET @Ten     = 10.0
SET @WholeAmt   = ROUND(@Amt,0, 1 )
SET @RoundedAmt = @Amt - @WholeAmt
SET @Decimal    = 16
WHILE @Decimal > @RoundToDecimal
BEGIN
SET @Decimal = @Decimal - 1 
IF 5 = ( ROUND(@RoundedAmt * POWER( @Ten, @Decimal + 1 ) ,0,1) - 
        (ROUND(@RoundedAmt * POWER( @Ten, @Decimal ) ,0,1) * 10) )
AND 0 = cast( ( ROUND(@RoundedAmt * POWER( @Ten, @Decimal ) ,0,1) - 
    (ROUND(@RoundedAmt * POWER( @Ten, @Decimal - 1 ) ,0,1) * 10) ) 
    AS INTEGER ) % 2
    SET @RoundedAmt = ROUND(@RoundedAmt,@Decimal, 1 )
ELSE 
    SET @RoundedAmt = ROUND(@RoundedAmt,@Decimal, 0 )
END
RETURN ( @RoundedAmt + @WholeAmt )
END
```

Comment: If you are storing numbers for financial calculations, you should probably use `decimal`, a fixed-point format.  If you are converting numbers to strings, I would suggest the `str()` function.

Comment: Consider using to Money / Smallmoney, which also have a lot better performance. Bankers rounding is financial. And btw., it is trivial to force it.

Comment: @TomTom I feel the same way about it being trivial

Comment: @GordonLinoff It's not really financial data, it is all scientific data dealing with liquid substance measurements and the data calculations deal only with division and multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server ROUND() function follows IEEE Standard 754 and uses the "round up" algorithm when you use float type. Use decimal if you need more precision. dont use use float or real.

refer this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187912.aspx

Comment: I ended up casting my float data to decimal, passing it to the UDF bankers rounding function, and then storing it back as a float and it worked great